# Excel: How can I set specific grid measurements?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want a grid with a row height and column width of exactly 5mm each.

As far as I understand grid-measurements can only be set in Page Layout viewmode.

However, when I put in 5mm for row height and column width, Excel automatically changes that to 4,76mm.

How can I create a grid with a row height of 5mm and a column width of 5mm?

Why is this so extremely difficult?

Comment: Have you changed the units in *File > Options > Advanced* under "Display" at "Ruler units"? However, Excel is not very good at calculating exact values.

Comment: Yes, ruler units are set to mm.

Comment: Excel will never get it exactly right, and it might also not obey everywhere Ruler units. It's just the way it's made.

Comment: Did you change them in the Ribbon- Home tab?

Answer (score 0):

From various miscellaneous sources over time, I've learned (I believe I have anyway) that MS internally sizes both width and height by the same number of elements per inch, so 10 of them wide is the same distance as 10 of them high. They are called `twips` and are claimed to be 1/20-th of 1 point in size with there being 72 points per inch. (Points are used by most everyone as a height measurement, not a width measurement, but MS uses whatever height that comes out to for both dimensions. So theoretically, MS could allow you to size a cell in 1,440-ths of an inch, or 0.00069444... inch segments (0.01763888... mm segments).

(Of course, they don't expose this to us in cell-side work. Of course.)

This means 56.6929+ twips per 1mm. Excel has to convert that to an integer since they do not do (apparently) decimals with the twips. So it becomes 27 twips that Excel can resolve to, internally. 27 twips is 5.02708333... mm.

In the measurement dialog boxes, one can set the size to hundredths of one's chosen measurement, in this case, millimeters. So 5.02708333... rounds to 5.03mm.

If you set a slightly larger than 5mm size, in this case guided by that 5.03mm size just mentioned, so, say, 5.10mm, Excel bumps down to the nearest of the sizes it can use which is 5.03mm. You can verify that by doing it yourself. The minimum size it resolves is split half above, half below that midpoint, so the next size down it can accept is 4.76mm and the size up is 5.29mm. So the exactness is probably determined with 5.027+mm being the midpoint then next, last, and this one are calculated then all three rounded.

And that doesn't take all the factors into account, there being borders for the cells and white space on all edges, etc., that may slightly cut down the full range between resolvable to hundredths of the larger measures we have to use slightly. Hence the 53mm range centered upon the shown hundredths of a millimeter midpoint.

The reason then, that you cannot get the precision that would seem possible is that Excel doesn't use the measuring systems we are forced to use and we have to live with the rounding involved. It is analogous to living with the errors that occur in the 15th significant digit of numbers due to the convention Excel uses for converting to and from binary number to compute with (from, almost always of course, decimal numbers) leading to obnoxious errors when combining calculated values which can now contain the errors vs. combining entered value which won't... even though MS claims to use 27 significant digits internally and so should be able to resolve such. MS really ought to have picked a base measuring system (inches of course, we're not animals using metric... oh, sorry dude...) and worked from it, cutting off display of characters at cell edge, as it does now anyway! But life is not that and maybe it made more sense in 1985 or so.

In any case, you cannot have better. I wager 5.03mm sizing is a lot better for your project than 4.76mm sizing, so consider using that as it might be satisfactory, and when future sizing doesn't work out, try some incrementing, and decrementing, to find the real measurement closest to what you desire.